# this is the question "write a program in C to pass the reference of an array to a function & print that array" ,this is not giving the output ,why?

Tags: c, declaration, function-call, variable-length-array

> **I got this question asked by one of my peer, as i don't know "C" that much, but still being a beginner i tried solving it, this is the
> approach i used, but it is not giving the expected output.**

> **According to the question, it should print the entered elements of an array, when we
> are passing the reference of an array to a function, can anyone review
> this code ?**

```
#include <stdio.h>
void print(int arr[], int n);

int main(){
    
    int n,i;
    int arr[n];

    printf("enter the size of array :");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    
    
    printf("enter elements :\n");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    print(&arr[i], n);
    
}

void print(int arr[], int n){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("\nentered elements are : %d",arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't say `int arr[n]` and then only later give `n` a value.

Comment: @SteveSummit  so, if i want to take input from the user for "array size"  then how would i be able to achieve that ?

Comment: The `void print(int arr[], int n)` function you've started to write is mostly correct.  But you want to call it from `main` as `print(arr, n);`.  You don't need the `&` — although the reason for that is surprising — and you *definitely* don't want the `[i]`, because here you're trying to pass — trying to get the same effect as if you had passed — the whole array, not just one element of it.

Comment: Why not prompt for and read the value of `n` from the user, *then* say `int arr[n];`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This declaration of the variable length array

```
int n,i;
int arr[n];
```

invokes undefined behavior because the variable `n` was not initialized.

Instead you need to write

```
int n,i;

printf("enter the size of array :");

if ( scanf("%d",&n) == 1 && n > 0 )
{
    int arr[n];
    // and so on
```

This call

```
print(&arr[i], n);
```

again leads to undefined behavior because the value of the variable i is equal to the size of the array. So the expression `&arr[i]` points to outside the array.

You need to write

```
print( arr, n);
```

It will be more correctly to declare and define the function like

```
void print( const int arr[], int n )
{
    printf( "\nentered elements are: " );
 
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", arr[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

Comment: @SadlyFullStack Yes. A parameter having an array type is adjusted by the compiler to pointer to the array element type.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow  now, it is taking user's input for "array size", also it is taking input for "array elements", but still it is not showing the expected output, as i have done some changes in the above code. kindly re-review that

Comment: @KarishmaSingh Reread my answer one more. I showed how the function must be called. And restore the original code in your question. Otherwise the question and answers will confuse readers.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow  okay, i have restored the original code

Answer (score 0):

Your Program is not giving output because you have not declared the size of array, i.e., instead of arr[n] write arr[100] or any other positive integer.
Else the code is error free.

Hope this is helpful.